# How to manually fix Qt PATH: fatal error RC1106: invalid option: -ologo, LNK1327 / LNK1158 : fatal error during running rc.exe

Tags: windows, qt

This is a rare problem some people have after installing the Qt IDE. With all the reports of a similar problem in VS I found it very hard to find the answer to this problem.

The problem is as follows: Qt searches for the PATH that VS uses. Qt fails to find correct PATH even if VS has the correct path. When it tries to compile and attempts to run rc.exe it cannot, because it has no idea where it is. It then throws the following compiler outputs depending on your configuration:

Compile output 1/2:

- 07:53:21: Running steps for project untitled...
- 07:53:21: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
- 07:53:21: Starting: "D:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
- D:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
- link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='' processorArchitecture=''" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\untitled.exe @C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Temp\untitled.exe.10340.16.jom
- fatal error RC1106: invalid option: -ologo
- LINK : fatal error LNK1327: failure during running rc.exe
- jom: D:\Documents\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MSVC2015_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\untitled.exe] Error 1327
- jom: D:\Documents\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MSVC2015_32bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
- 07:53:22: The process "D:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
- Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Desktop Qt 5.11.0 MSVC2015 32bit)
- The kit Desktop Qt 5.11.0 MSVC2015 32bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
- When executing step "Make"
- 07:53:22: Elapsed time: 00:00.

Compile Output 2/2:

- 11:23:23: Running steps for project untitled3...
- 11:23:23: Starting: "D:\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe" D:\Documents\untitled3\untitled3.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
- Info: creating stash file D:\Documents\build-untitled3-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2015_32bit-Debug.qmake.stash
- 11:23:23: The process "D:\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
- 11:23:23: Starting: "D:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" qmake_all
- jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
- 11:23:23: The process "D:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
- 11:23:23: Starting: "D:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
- D:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
- D:\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\bin\uic.exe ..\untitled3\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
- cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\untitled3.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\untitled3 -I. -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtWidgets -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtGui -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtANGLE -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -I\include -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.11648.16.jom
- cl -BxD:\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -E ....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\mkspecs\features\data\dummy.cpp 2>NUL >debug\moc_predefs.h
- main.cpp
- cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\untitled3.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\untitled3 -I. -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtWidgets -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtGui -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtANGLE -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -I\include -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.11648.31.jom
- mainwindow.cpp
- D:\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --compiler-flavor=msvc --include debug/moc_predefs.h -ID:/Qt/5.11.1/msvc2015/mkspecs/win32-msvc -ID:/Documents/untitled3 -ID:/Qt/5.11.1/msvc2015/include -ID:/Qt/5.11.1/msvc2015/include/QtWidgets -ID:/Qt/5.11.1/msvc2015/include/QtGui -ID:/Qt/5.11.1/msvc2015/include/QtANGLE -ID:/Qt/5.11.1/msvc2015/include/QtCore -I. -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" ..\untitled3\mainwindow.h -o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
- cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\untitled3.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\untitled3 -I. -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtWidgets -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtGui -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtANGLE -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -I\include -I....\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mainwindow.obj.11648.375.jom
- moc_mainwindow.cpp
- link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='' processorArchitecture=''" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\untitled3.exe @C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Temp\untitled3.exe.11648.1359.jom
- LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
- jom: D:\Documents\build-untitled3-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2015_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\untitled3.exe] Error 1158
- jom: D:\Documents\build-untitled3-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2015_32bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
- 11:23:25: The process "D:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
- Error while building/deploying project untitled3 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.11.1 MSVC2015 32bit)
- The kit Desktop Qt 5.11.1 MSVC2015 32bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
- When executing step "Make"
- 11:23:25: Elapsed time: 00:02.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Build and Run -> Kits -> (The kit you are using) -> then adding the proper directory to the Environment with the "PATH=${PATH};" command. Example in attachments. To find the file path, follow mine to the bin folder and select the one you need.

[image]

Thanks to @aha_1980 @kkoehne and @J.Hilk over at: https://forum.qt.io/topic/92145/qt-cannot-find-rc-exe-codes-fatal-error-rc1106-invalid-option-ologo-lnk1327-lnk1158-fatal-error-during-running-rc-exe